# EOFError using pickle.load()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I have the following code:

```
pos = [
    [('the', 'DT'), ('rabbit', 'NN'), ... ],
    [('he', 'PRP'), ('jokes', 'VBZ'), ... ],
    ...
]
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(pos, f)
```

Then I want to load the content:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    pos = [pickle.load(f) for i in range(the_length)]
```

But then I get this exception:

```
...

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError

EOFError
```

Actually, the first list in `pos` is correctly loaded (`[('the', 'DT'), ('rabbit', 'NN'), ... ]`) but the exception occurs just after.
If I open the file, there is indeed something wrong: all the sentences are stored but the file ends with a long list like this:

```
aa(lp269
a(lp270
a(lp271
a(lp272
a(lp273
a(lp274
a(lp275
...
a(lp3531
a.
```

(I tried to open the file with `rb` and `wb` instead of `r` and `w` but it doesn't solve anything)

Comment: you are dumping a list and trying to load elements of a list.  you have to load a list

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I think in a previous version of my code I called `dump` for each list of `pos` in a loop and that's why I call `load` in a loop. Thks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one `dump` call, you should only have one `load` call.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    pos = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: Well I think in a previous version of my code I called `dump` for each list of `pos` in a loop and that's why I call `load` in a loop. I should have seen the problem... Thank you. (I check it tomorrow at work before to accept your answer)